# Objective-c intermediate step build between source code and binary

Tags: objective-c, compiler-construction

Is there any solution to get an objective-c source code just after setters and getters have been generated?

Comment: what do you want it for? I personally do not know of a way to get intermediate code, but there may be another approach depending on what you want.

Comment: I want to see-demonstrate concretely how setters and getters are expanded when they are generated with property-synthesize

Answer (score 2):

I don't think synthesized accessors are textually generated as Objective-C source code. You can see the generated assembly by passing the -S flag to Clang or GCC.